# Nuxt: Securely authorising API routes with serverMiddleware

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js

I want to utilise Nuxt's `serverMiddleware` to handle API calls from an SSR Nuxt application. There are essentially 2 options for doing so:

- Implement the full API in `serverMiddleware`
- Implement the full API as a standalone service, and 'proxy' calls to it via `serverMiddleware`

In either case I want API calls to be authorised solely for the Nuxt application front-end. There is not a user login system, but I do not want any routes exposed by `serverMiddleware` to be callable from anywhere other than the host running them.

In the second instance, even if my standalone API is fully internal and any secrets are contained within `serverMiddleware` - simply calling the `serverMiddleware` routes exposed by Nuxt would essentially give access to the internal API.

So the **tl;dr**: - how can I sufficiently lockdown `serverMiddleware` routes such that they only accessible by the Nuxt application running on the same host?